# Google Maps API v3 opacity overlapping

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a sales area for a client using google maps. The area in question has three main hubs and there is some overlap from each. The example can be found on http://citytosurfwhitegoods.com.au/map.php

What I am after is to switch off the alpha combining feature. Is there some flag or attribute for this to occur? or does anyone have a suggestion?